# Highchart not showing - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, highcharts

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL database and display on a column chart using HIghChart but nothing seems to be showing.

This is my view:

```
<div id="last7days">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //var data_click = 4;
            //var data_viewer = 5;
            Highcharts.chart('last7days', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Last 7 days Transactions'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: jdata.date, //['2013','2014','2015', '2016']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount(in naira)'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Credit',
                    data: jdata.credit
                },{
                    name: 'Debit',
                    data: jdata.debit
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Find attached, here is the json data being returned by the controller

```
{"date":["2017-12-20","2017-12-21","2017-12-22"],"credit":["500600.00","2000.00","5600.00"],"debit":["0.00","0.00","47582.00"]}
```

Update:
I think its because the numbers in the array are in quotes, how do I remove the quotes?

Comment: Now ask the __exact__ question.

Comment: @u_mulder I think its because the numbers in the array are in quotes, how do I remove the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Simply add JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK to your json_encode() function in the controller.
For example, 
json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)